# how access functions from express.js to client side through buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
app.get('/showusers/del', function(req, res){
    Users.remove({fname: 'usman'});
    res.send("removed.");
});

app.get('/remove', function(req, res){
    Users.remove({}, function(err){
        res.send('removed');
        console.log("done");
    });
});
```

I want to access these functions through button in client side

Answer (score 0):

The functions are server-sided. That means you cannot access them the 'usual' way, as the client-side will **never** be able to communicate with the server-side like they would with regular javascript functions.

You can only build [Ajax calls](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to access the URL's and thereby triggering the functions.

For example, to trigger the `get` function `/showusers/del`, you can use the following snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/showusers/del"
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```